# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql

I get this error, Can anyone help me in finding my mistake in the query?

```
public boolean populateLeagues(String leaguename, String password){

        Connect connect = new Connect();
        Connection conn = connect.Connection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();            
        String query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('" + leaguename + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Even if this worked, you shouldn't do it. You should use a prepared statement with parameters instead.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should rewrite it using parameterized queries. See [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java) for guidance.

Comment: @Srikanth: What do you mean by "has values"?

Comment: Also, how come your code never uses `password`?

Comment: @Jon I mean leaguename is not empty.. it is getting values from a calling funtion

Comment: @ruakh- just wanted to check if it works for one parameter..

Comment: You use single quote around leaguename, since we don't know how leaguename is formatted, that might lead to errors.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau- using single quotes worked thank you :) I am new to stackoverflow hence I don't know how to vote up the replies

Comment: `"INSERT INTO users VALUES(('" + leaguename + "'))";` this statement worked

Comment: @Srikanth Look at the right answer and, below votes number, you'll find a checker that can become green. Click it to accept the answer.

Comment: @Alfabravo- It says minimum 15 reputations required to vote up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Jon Skeet says, use a prepared statement and inject parameters into. In this way you don't have to figure out all hassles about sql injection and data format(think about using a query like the one you provide to store datetime globally).
Probably `leaguename` value is `null`. Remember that default value for string type isn't the empty strin but `null`

Answer (score -1):

You use single quote around `leaguename`, since we don't know how `leaguename` is formatted, that might lead to errors